# Error: redux-persist: config.storage is required. Try using one of the provided storage engines `import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'`

Tags: react-native

//my store

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducer/index";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import {persistReducer,persistStore} from "redux-persist";

const persistConfig={
    key:'root',
    Storage:AsyncStorage
};
const persistedReducer=persistReducer(persistConfig,rootReducer)

export default()=>{

    let store=createStore(persistedReducer)
    let persistor=persistStore(store)
    return {store,persistor}
}
```

// I have already a redux persist installed but i don't know why i am getting this error
i am just creating the simple app which will increase the number after taping the button but i want to store the state even if user close the app so i used persit but i don't know why i am getting this error
//====>App.js page

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect}from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button ,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {numIncrement} from './reduxConfig/Action'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react';
import {reduxStore} from './reduxConfig/store';



const Root = () => {
  const dispatch=useDispatch();

  const txt=useSelector(state => state.reducer.count);
  console.log("ddd",txt)

  return(
   <View>
   
  <Text style={styles.txxt}>ddd{txt}</Text>
  <View style={styles.btn}>
 <Button title='counter' onPress={()=>dispatch(numIncrement())}/>
  </View>
</View>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const {store,persistor}=reduxStore()
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
    <Root/>
    </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
  txxt:{
    fontSize:100,
    color:"black"
  },
  btn:{
    top:200
  }
 
})
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are uppercase S for storage in persistConfig.use "storage" instead